# JPA: OneToOne relation owner

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I want to make a relation between 2 models by `User.id` and `Address.user_id` columns.

I have created two tables with One-To-One relations:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private Address address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address extends com.mezoline.domain.common.Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private User user;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Here I can already see the problem: hibernate did not generate database column `Address.user_id` how I expected.

I create `Address` instance and add that to `User`:

```
    User user = entityManager.find(User.class, 69);
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setCity("Тест");
    userTransaction.begin();
    user.setAddress(address);
    entityManager.merge(user);
    userTransaction.commit();
```

After I call `merge(user)`. Data success saved... without any relation info.

UPD:

With config below, JPA will create relation column `Address.user_id` (just relation owner was swapped)

```
public class User { 
    ...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Address address;
    ...
}

public class Address {
    ....
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    ....
}
```

But after save `Address.user_id` is null... (other columns are being filled)

UPD2:

Thanks. Second config work fine, when was set the inverse side relation field (as suggested in the comments):

```
Address address = createAddress();
address.setUser(user);
user.setAddress(address);
```

***But I don`t understand, why first config (where the User is the owning side)  don`t work.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because there is a logical error in your expectations about the initial config.

You declared `User` to be the *owning* side of the relationship. *Owning* means the foreign key representing the relationship will be kept in the `USER` table, not in the `Address` table.

At the same time, you annotated `User.address` with `@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")`. Basically, I think you're trying to force the `ADRESS` table to hold the foreign key. But in that case, **`Adress` should be the owning side**.

If you want the initial config to work, all you should do is you should replace the current `JoinColumn` annotation with `@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")`. The foreign key will end up in the `USER` table. When persisting the entities, `User.address` must be set; setting `Address.user` is optional.

If you absolutely need to have the key in the `ADDRESS` table, make the `Address` table the owning side (you will then only have to ensure `Address.user` is set at persist time; however, you will still want the `User.address` to be set in order for the cascade to work, unless you persist the `Address` entity explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

Because it's *bidirectional* `One-to-One`, you also need to set the *inverse side* to so-called parent entity before persisting the parent/super entity.

```
Address addr =  new Address()
user.setAddress(addr);
addr.setUser(user);
session.save(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would stay with original config, where the user is the owning side. It makes more sense to me regarding your schema.

Regarding the `user_id` column on Address.. you have to make sure that the dependencies are set on both sides of the relationship. So your transanctional method should contain following:

```
if (user.getAddress() == null) {
    Address address = createAddress();
    address.setUser(user);
    user.setAddress(address);        
}
```

Answer (score -2):

@crizzis explained very well, I was trying to save an Employee object and Address object and making the Address table to have the foreign key, but the Employee object was owning the relationship, after going by your instructions changed the ownership to Employee now the foreign key is getting updated fine.

Comment: Please, avoid posting "thank you" answers. If something worked for you, upvote the answer :)